# Flickr integration for Careers 2.0

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, images

It would be nice to share images of some of my projects.

My profile page looks very nice and I wish there was some place I could post images.

Maybe even better if the galleries were somehow integrated deeper into Careers, so that they could sit nicely.

Comment: Mockup will be nice and help us see what you mean.

Comment: You can use Markdown in Careers as well, so you can use the `![alt text](http://flickr.com/image.jpg)` syntax in the description.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the text fields on the profile are markdown enabled, so you can use the inline image syntax to add an image.

```
![Alt Text](http://link.to/image.jpg)
```